# What could cause an extra bit to be added to a result in a non-blocking assignment?

Tags: verilog, cpu-architecture, xilinx

I'm trying to create an instruction decoder in Verilog using Xilinx. My apologies for not having the cleanest code, I'm still learning Verilog. The issue I am having is that my FS result is incorrect.

I expect to see 00010 but instead I see 01010. As I debug, I changed the FS non-blocking assignment for ADD from 00010 to 01010 just to see what the result would be and I end up with FS being 10010. This leads me to believe that the bit[3] of FS is adding an extra 1 somehow. This is my verilog code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`include "OPCODES.vh"

module instructiondecoder(

input [31:0] instruction,

//Control Word Values
output reg       RW,
output reg [1:0] MD,
output reg [1:0] BS,
output reg       PS,
output reg       MW,
output reg [4:0] FS,
output reg       MB,    
output reg       MA,
output reg       CS,
output     [4:0] AA,
output     [4:0] BA
);

assign AA = instruction[19:15];
assign BA = instruction[14:10];

initial begin
RW <=     0;
MD <=    00;
BS <=    00;
PS <=     0;
MW <=     0;
FS <= 00000;
MB <=     0;
MA <=     0;
CS <=     0;

end

always @ (instruction)
begin
case(instruction[31:25])
    `NOP: 
        begin
                    RW <=     0;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     0;
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end 
    `ADD:
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00010;
                    MB <=     0;
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `SUB: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00101;
                    MB <=     0;
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `SLT: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    10;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00101;
                    MB <=     0;
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end 
    `AND: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01000;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `OR: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01010;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `XOR: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01100;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `ST: 
        begin
                    RW <=     0;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     1;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `LD: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    01;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `ADI: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00010;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     1;
        end
    `SBI: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00101;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     1;
        end
    `NOT: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01110;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `ANI: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01000;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `ORI: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01010;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `XRI: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 01100;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `AIU: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00010;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `SIU: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00101;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `MOV: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `LSL: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 10100;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `LSR: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 11000;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `JMR: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    00;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 11000;
                    MB <=     0;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     0;
        end
    `BZ: 
        begin
                    RW <=     0;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    01;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     1;
        end
    `BNZ: 
        begin
                    RW <=     0;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    01;
                    PS <=     1;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     1;
        end
    `JMP: 
        begin
                    RW <=     0;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    11;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00000;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     0;
                    CS <=     1;
        end
    `JML: 
        begin
                    RW <=     1;
                    MD <=    00;
                    BS <=    11;
                    PS <=     0;
                    MW <=     0;
                    FS <= 00111;
                    MB <=     1;    
                    MA <=     1;
                    CS <=     1;
        end

    default :           
        begin
                    RW <=     1'bx;
                    MD <=    2'bxx;
                    BS <=    2'bxx;
                    PS <=     1'bx;
                    MW <=     1'bx;
                    FS <= 5'bxxxxx;
                    MB <=     1'bx; 
                    MA <=     1'bx;
                    CS <=     1'bx;
        end

endcase
end

endmodule
```

The following is my OPCODES include:

```
`ifndef OP_CODES
`define OP_CODES

`define NOP 7'b0000000
`define ADD 7'b0000010
`define SUB 7'b0000101
`define SLT 7'b1100010
`define AND 7'b0001000
`define OR  7'b0001010
`define XOR 7'b0001100
`define ST  7'b0000001
`define LD  7'b0100001
`define ADI 7'b0100010
`define SBI 7'b0100101
`define NOT 7'b0101110
`define ANI 7'b0101000
`define ORI 7'b0101010
`define XRI 7'b0101100
`define AIU 7'b1100010
`define SIU 7'b1000101
`define MOV 7'b1000000
`define LSL 7'b0110000
`define LSR 7'b0110001
`define JMR 7'b1100001
`define BZ  7'b0100000
`define BNZ 7'b1100000
`define JMP 7'b1000100
`define JML 7'b0000111

`endif
```

And in this is my test:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
`include "OPCODES.vh"


module instructionDecoder_test;

// Inputs
reg [31:0] instruction;

// Outputs
wire RW;
wire [1:0] MD;
wire [1:0] BS;
wire PS;
wire MW;
wire [4:0] FS;
wire MA;
wire MB;
wire CS;
wire [4:0] AA;
wire [4:0] BA;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
instructiondecoder uut (
    .instruction(instruction), 
    .RW(RW), 
    .MD(MD), 
    .BS(BS), 
    .PS(PS), 
    .MW(MW), 
    .FS(FS), 
    .MA(MA), 
    .MB(MB), 
    .CS(CS), 
    .AA(AA), 
    .BA(BA)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
    instruction = {`ADD, 5'd8, 5'd3, 5'd5, 10'b0}; //ADD


end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write (below) the Right hand side is an Integer (Decimal, base10), not binary (base2). Only use non-blocking when implying flip-flops.

```
initial begin
  RW <=     0;
  MD <=    00;
  BS <=    00;
  PS <=     0;
  MW <=     0;
  FS <= 00000;
  MB <=     0;
  MA <=     0;
  CS <=     0;
end
```

What you want is:

```
initial begin
  RW = 'b0    ;
  MD = 'b00   ;
  BS = 'b00   ;
  PS = 'b0    ;
  MW = 'b0    ;
  FS = 'b00000;
  MB = 'b0    ;
  MA = 'b0    ;
  CS = 'b0    ;
end
```

NB: You do not need to to include leading 0's although it can help readability.

To add to [Will's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514869/will) comment, It is recommended to size your numbers (`5'b10110` instead of `'b10110`), I do however tend to leave reset or initial conditions un-sized to minimise the refactoring required for code changes.

Other available options for number bases in verilog are:

```
'b0 // Binary      (base2)
'o0 // Octal       (base8)
'd0 // Decimal     (base10)
'h0 // Hexadecimal (base16)
```

Comment: it can be helpful to include the length of your literals too.  Instead of 'b00000 you can write 5'b00000.   Your tools will then tell you when you're trying to write literals into registers with sizes that don't match.  This is helpful because it is a way of spotting mistakes early.